# About Ganesha's wife, Pushti

Tags: identification-request, ganesha

In [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57331.html) of Devi Bhagavata Purana, it mentioned Ganesha's another wife, Pushti:-

> O Child! As Lakṣmī Devī is of Nārāyaṇa, as Rādhikā is of Kṛṣṇa; as is My Sāvītrī, as Bhava’s is Bhavānī, as Boar’s is Earth, as Yajña’s is Dakṣīṇā, Atri’s Anasūyā, Gautama’s Ahalyā, Moon’s Rohiṇī, Brihaspati’s Tārā, Manu’s Śatarūpā, Kandarpa’s Rati, Kaśyapa’s Aditi, Vaśiṣṭha’s Arundhatī, Karddama’s Devahūti, Fire’s Svāhā, Indra’s Śacī, **Gaṇeśa’s Puṣṭi**, Skanda’s Devasenā, and Dharma’s Mūrti, so let you be the dear wife of Śaṅkhacūḍa.

We know about Ganesha had two wives, Siddhi and Buddhi (sometimes Riddhi) but How did he married Pushti? First of all, Who is this Pushti and any infos about her?